# Quartz with Cosmos db

Tags: jdbc, azure-cosmosdb, quartz

According to the [documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09.html)

> JDBCJobStore works with nearly any database: Oracle, PostgreSQL,
> MySQL, MS SQLServer, HSQLDB, and DB2.

But, is it possible to use Cosmos db as Quartz Job Store? Which steps should I do?
I have found a Job store [implementation](https://github.com/Oriflame/cosmosdb-quartznet) but it's for .NET platform and nothing was found for Java.

Comment: This really is something you'll need to try yourself. Reading the docs, you can see that all of the listed databases are relational (and Cosmos DB is not a relational store). There are JDBC and ODBC drivers for Cosmos DB, but this is something you'd need to see how it would work with Quartz. Perhaps reach out to their tech support? (this is unfortunately off-topic here, as this really is a support question)

Comment: I agree with @David, and it's better to try it first by yourself. If you met some error, you could put them here with what you had done and ask for advice.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Sorry, you are absolutely right. But your answer is not clear to me. Do you suggest that I should find JDBC driver for Cosmos DB and try it?
And, yes, I am going to write some questions to the Quartz support soon.

Comment: @ArtemDanilin - I really don't have an answer for you. My point is that you're trying to use a 3rd-party tool with Cosmos DB, and there doesn't appear to be any direct support for this. There are drivers that exists (both JDBC and ODBC), for connecting apps with Cosmos DB, but I have no idea if you'll be able to incorporate those drivers with Quartz. And really, this is a discussion you need to have with the folks who maintain Quartz. That's all I'm saying.